# How to read data from nested YAML file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have for example swagger.yaml file and I want read some variable from it.
For example that file: https://editor.swagger.io/

Bellow is fragment of file.
Is possible to get eg. values of the "parameters"? It is best to assign them to some variables.

```
paths:
  /pet:
    post:
      tags:
      - "pet"
      summary: "Add a new pet to the store"
      description: ""
      operationId: "addPet"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      - "application/xml"
      produces:
      - "application/xml"
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "Pet object that needs to be added to the store"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Pet"
      responses:
        405:
          description: "Invalid input"
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - "write:pets"
        - "read:pets"
```

I've got that code:

```
import yaml

path_to_yaml = '../data/swagger.yaml'

with open(path_to_yaml) as f:
    dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f)
print(yaml.dump(dataMap, default_flow_style=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by installing `scalpl`
https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

to get eg. value of name ("body"):

```
with open(file.yaml) as f:
    dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f)
proxy = Cut(dataMap)
print(proxy['paths.pet.post.parameters.name']
```

results:

```
>>> body
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a dictionary to access the values of the parameters.

For that install [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/)

```
import yaml
yaml_as_python_dict = yaml.load(yaml_as_string_or_bytes)
```

And then it's simply accessing via the keys to obtain the value

For example,

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
print "dict['Name']: ", dict['Name']
print "dict['Age']: ", dict['Age']
```

Comment: Also do note that, it does have the tendency to fail on uncontrolled YAML input. For that, you may use [this](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) which effectively achieves the same job. But then again its up to you to make the decision.